# Why $k(\mathbb A^n)=k(T_1,\ldots,T_n)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

The book I'm reading defines the dimension of a quasi-projective variety $X$ as

$$\dim (X)=trdeg(k(X)|k)$$

Since $K(X)$ is a field containing $k$, dimension is well-defined.

In order to prove that $\dim(\mathbb A^n)=n$, the author says:

$k(\mathbb A^n)=k(T_1,\ldots,T_n)\implies trdeg(k(\mathbb A^n)|k)=n$

I didn't understand why the field of fractions of $k[\mathbb A^n]$ is equal to the  $k(T_1,\ldots,T_n)$.

In this context is $k(T_1,\ldots,T_n)$ the polynomial ring or the field of rational functions in $n$ variables?

If $k(T_1,\ldots,T_n)$ is the field of rational functions in $n$ variables I don't know why $trdeg(k(T_1\ldots,T_n)|k)=n$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $k(T_1,\dotsc,T_n)$ is *by definition* the field of fractions of $k[T_1,\dotsc,T_n]$. Better learn these things properly before going into algebraic geometry.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg sometimes I'm confusing with this notation

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 3):

The coordinate ring $k[{\mathbb A}^n]$ is $k[T_1, \dots, T_n]$, the polynomial ring in $n$ variables over $k$; the function field $k({
\mathbb A}^n)$ is $k(T_1, \dots, T_n)$, the field of rational functions in $n$ variables over $k$, which is the field of fractions of $k[T_1, \dots, T_n]$.

As for $\text{trdeg}$: this is the transcendence degree and $k(T_1, \dots, T_n)$ is the prototypical field of transcendence degree $n$ over $k$; $\{T_1, \dots, T_n\}$ is a maximal algebraically independent set.

Comment: How can I prove formally that $\{T_1,\ldots,T_n\}$ is an algebraically independent set? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Purely by definition; there is hardly anything to prove.  Say $f(X_1, \dots, X_n) \in k[X_1, \dots, X_n]$ is a polynomial such that $f(T_1, \dots, T_n) = 0$ (in $k(T_1, \dots, T_n)$). Then $f(X_1, \dots, X_n) = 0$.

Comment: Why $f(T_1,\ldots,T_n)=0$ in $k(T_1,\ldots,T_n)$ implies that $f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=0$?

Comment: For exactly the same reason that $a/1 = 0 \in {\mathbb Q}$ implies $a = 0 \in {\mathbb Z}$: by definition.

Comment: thank you very much, I think I understood